# How to use a parquet file data in PySpark?

Tags: pyspark

I have two parquet files as given below:

1. `df1 = spark.read.parquet("...")`
2. `df2 = spark.read.parquet("...")`

I have a function `funcA()` which needs to use **df2** to do some work. I want to apply this function to every row of **df1**, `df1.foreach(funcA)`, but it raises the following error:

> You are attempting to reference SparkContext from a broadcast
> variable, action, or transformation. SparkContext can only be used on
> the driver, not in code that runs on workers. For more information,
> see SPARK-5063.

I have tried many methods but none of them worked. How to solve this problem?

Comment: Please edit your question to contain a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so that reviewers don't lose their time with trying to recreate your situation, but can put their time into actually answering your question. Also, please define explicitly what your wanted behaviour is.

Comment: w.r.t. error message, please share your function and explain what you're trying to do in it. it seems you're creating a spark context within an UDF which isn't allowed.